# Modifying views exposed filter query string

Tags: views

I'm looking for a way to modify views' resulting query string (URL) after applying a filter, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I have a view with exposed filters, taxonomy lists to be specific. Hitting apply generates something like:  www.mysite.com/myview?foo=123
My goal is to have it instead generate:  www.mysite.com/myview?foo=bar

I know views' exposed filters depends on tid for the filter to work when visiting a page (e.g. pasting a link and visiting the page), and I have some `hook_views_pre_build`code to handle that. My issue is going the other direction. What hook, function, or other approach can I use to modify that?

For reference I've tried replacing view object contents in `hook_views_pre_build`, `hook_views_post_build`, `hook_views_pre_execute`, `hook_views_post_execute`, and `hook_views_query_alter`, but nothing seems to have the desired effect. I do not want contextual filters due to the need for order independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a solution using `hook_views_pre_render` combined with a JS `history.replacestate`. More of a workaround, but it does the job. Would still like to find a way to modify the view object or a PHP hook though.

Here's a stripped down version of the php hook implementation:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == "myviewname") {
    $path_settings = array("mymodule" => array('query_params' => array()));
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $val){
      if (array_key_exists($key, $view->exposed_input)) {
        $path_settings['mymodule']['query_params'][$key] = $view->exposed_input[$key];
      }
    }
    drupal_add_js($path_settings, 'setting');
  }
}
```

Then in the module's js attached behaviors:

```
function tidyViewsQueryString() {
  currentLocation = window.location.href;
  for (var key in Drupal.settings.mymodule.query_params) {
    if (Drupal.settings.mymodule.query_params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      currentLocation = updateUrlParameter(currentLocation, key, Drupal.settings.mymodule.query_params[key])
    }
  }
  if (currentLocation != window.location.href){
    window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, currentLocation);
  }
}

//From https://gist.github.com/niyazpk/f8ac616f181f6042d1e0
function updateUrlParameter(uri, key, value) {
    // remove the hash part before operating on the uri
    var i = uri.indexOf('#');
    var hash = i === -1 ? ''  : uri.substr(i);
         uri = i === -1 ? uri : uri.substr(0, i);

    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re)) {
        if (value.length > 0)
          uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        else 
          uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + '$2')
    } else {
        uri = uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }
    return uri + hash;  // finally append the hash as well
}
```